# Building and deploying application to Windows Phone 7.5 device from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

I am unable to create an app for Windows phone 7.5 [Nokia Lumia 900] or deploy app to the phone from Visual Studio 2012. I have installed Windows Phone 8.0 SDK. Can anyone give me steps to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download and install [**Zune desktop app**](http://www.xbox.com/zune) to deploy apps to WP7 devices.

Once it is installed, launch it, it will connect to your device and you then should the be able to deploy and debug apps from Visual Studio.

Comment: Have done this. Still it is not deploying. I also have unlocked the device for Development.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474 did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The SDK includes a tool called "Windows Phone Developer Registration". Once you've registered with the marketplace you can use this tool to unlock a device and deploy to it directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Have done this. Still it is not deploying. I also have unlocked the device for Development.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474 did work me. WP 8 SDK earlier did not support 7.8 phones. Need to update 7.8 SDK before testing on 7.8 devices.